# European citizen with layover in United States – what documents do I need?

Tags: usa, france, layovers, covid-19, belgian-citizens

I'm confused by how the US travel ban apply to layovers.

I have a flight from Papeete (French Polynesia) to Paris on October 4 2020. **The flight stops at Los Angeles Airport** for 2h30.

I will be travelling with a Belgian passport.

What extra documents do I need?

Comment: What airline are you flying on? Air Tahiti Nui flights from Papeete to Paris are scheduled to stop in Vancouver rather than LAX in September and October. Air France flights until the end of September are scheduled to stop in Vancouver as well. They probably just haven't updated the schedules for October yet, but as long as the current restrictions remain in effect there's a good chance they will reroute those flights as well.

Comment: Air France. Ok, that would make much more sense. The departing (Paris >> Papeete) stops at Vancouver, but for some reason the returning flight (Papeete >> Paris) stops at LAX; which I initially did not notice when booking. I would indeed find it surprising they sell these tickets if layover in the US is impossible for many passengers. If I look at earlier dates (eg. early September) both departing & returning are via Vancouver, which seems to confirm what you are saying. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

The travel ban applies to layovers in the same way as it applies to all travellers.  Transit for passengers travelling from the Schengen area (or other areas covered by the travel ban) to another area is not permitted (unless they fall into an exempt category). Transit for passengers in the other direction is permitted without any special COVID requirements in effect.